# Solid state relay Crydom D1D07 closes and remains closed

Tags: solid-state-relay

I have a [Crydom D1D07](http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/1-dc-series-dc-panel-mount.pdf) solid state relay and the control side is a +5 V DC on terminal 3 and a +3.4 V DC (don't ask) on terminal 4.

When terminal 4 is switched to ground (from +3.4 V DC) the SSR closes and the output side closes and passes the voltage as expected.

However, when the control side goes back to +3.4 V DC from ground the SSR does not open but remains closed and so the output side continues to pass voltage.

SSR:

- The minimum on voltage is 3.5 V DC
- Minimum input current is 10 mA for on state
- Must turn off voltage is 1 V DC
- Impedance is current regulated

It seems the must turn off voltage is not being met.

Adding a 370 Ω resistor to the terminal 4 side corrects this failure above but I still do not see how it does. The math does not compute. I think the voltage goes from 3.4 V DC to 3.7 V DC with the resistor added.

Comment: What is the nature of your 3.4 V source? Is it able to sink current? What other loads are attached to it?

Comment: 1.  it just ties that lead to ground when told to.   2.  the resistor is 437 ohms, not 370.

Comment: How does it produce 3.4 V when it needs to do that?

Comment: it just does by default.  Hopefully this detail does not matter to this situation... it just is what it is right now and I cannot change that input voltage except with the resistor.

Comment: So what you connect to terminal 4 is either a short to ground, nothing at all (which results in 3.4 V on the terminal), or 437 ohms to +5 V?

Comment: The off state leakage current to ground is your problem. The fix is a pullup resistor. Your series R is a marginal poor solution.

Comment: I'm confused, where is the 3.4V coming from?  How do you expect to turn off the SSR if you apply 1.6 volts (5V - 3.4V) across the input when it's supposed to be less than 1 volt to turn it off.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to switch the high side?  It's voltage operated not current operated.  Have a look at this: http://www.omron.com.au/service_support/FAQ/FAQ02155/index.asp.  They suggest adding a bleeder resistor across the input terminals.

Comment: It sounds like OP is using an SSR triac to switch DC. (It doesn't work.)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the input as specified.

```
Minimum Turn-On Voltage (6) 3.5 VDC
Must Turn-Off Voltage 1 VDC    ( your circuit is 5-3.4 = 1.6V too high )
Minimum Input Current (for on-state) 10 mA   (unknown)
Maximum Input Current 15 mA    ( your value is unknown)
```

You can specify your options available to you for driving or someone can tell you how to do it.

This is the input behaviour.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2xYEK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These are a couple of options of many more.

[image]

This is exactly what I expect  Crydom has on their inside design.

Since the current limiter needs 1.5V for IR LED and + 2V for current limiter, This is why you see 3.5V on an open circuit input but there must be enough leakage to trigger the MOSFET.

Using the pull-up resistor causes the input voltage difference to be zero ( both at 5V. ) and this draws little or no current and turns off the IR LED..

Comment: I see the 5.0 - 3.4 is 1.6   but the 430ohm resistor changes it to 5.0 - 3.7 is 1.3  Still above the 1 vdc must turn off.  YET it works this way!   I do not know how to test the max current with my fluke 179, so can we assume that is OK?

Comment: Can you say how your driver looks?

Comment: sorry, and thank you, but unfortunately I do not know enough about circuit diagrams for these from the datasheet for the crydom to help me understand this problem.

Comment: Just put a 10k resistor across the inputs to turn off. I see you are using a normally open switch to ground.

Comment: i realize its probably atypical to have a unequal voltage on each of the two control terminals, but this is what I have to use at this point, and can only make the resistor change to make the setup work.  I just do not understand why this makes it work yet, and would like to understand this or see the math prove it out.

Comment: I dont know why you cannot describe how you are connecting the inputs.

Comment: The terminal 3 is a +5VDC source from a power supply.   The terminal 4 has +3.4VDC from an input that can tie it to ground when i decide to. This 3.4vdc source also has that ground tied to the RTN of the +5 power supply. But if that wire connection back to the RTN is removed, there is still a path to ground for the +3.4 source tied to the electrical system ground -utility power for the whole system, as is the +5 power supply. Everything goes to this single point ground from the utility power panel.

Comment: Do you understand that an open switch is not an option for Off? Unless you use a pullup resistor across the inputs 3&4 ?  High impedance seems to have some 1mA of leakage which prevents the voltage between the pins to go to <=1V in the datasheet.  Your solution seems to work for now, but my understanding tells me it is not a reliable solution but I understand it.

Comment: Are you saying i can use the crydon’s control side screw down terminals #3 and #4 and hardwire a 10k ohm resistor directly from terminal 3 to terminal 4, Instead of just the 430 ohm resistor on the wire going from the +3.4vdc source to #4?

Comment: Yes that is across 3 & 4

Comment: A picture of older Crydom SSR's constant current circuitry is shown here in Section 4.1, Fig 4-1: https://www.galco.com/techdoc/crdm/d4840_crdmh1.pdf.  The newer circuitry probably uses what @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 described.  The handbook describes driving techniques in section 6.  Coverage of leakage from the drive source in section 6.3.  It is common to add a bleeder resistor across the input terminals of the SSR, see (1) http://www.omron.com.au/service_support/FAQ/FAQ02155/index.asp and (2) https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/precautions_ssr.pdf

Comment: @oldo Are you using 5V source **AND** a 3.4V source across the inputs to turn off the device?  Where exactly are you getting the 3.4V source from?  What is your switching device that causes 3.4V to go to ground?  Explain how the input is set up so people can actually help you properly instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwPDVq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transistor provides the voltage gain and offset you need to keep the SSR off when the control voltage is higher than about 2.7VDC. It also does not pull the driving output high (like above 3.3V) , which may be a latent issue for you, and retains the same logic (low = ON).

Comment: Common base will not pull up the input and  this will result in the same voltage as no transistor. Into the leaky current source with 1mA @ 3.4V that pulls down to 10mA

Comment: Sounds like @oldo is trying to use two separate sources across the input terminals to turn the SSR off, no idea why.  Maybe 5V is fixed and the 3.4V source is the only one he can control.  If he uses the circuit described above and connects the 3.4V (/GND) source into the emitter of the NPN, he should get the desired result.